# Getting all the value from a checked checkbox and put into a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have all my checkbox value put into a text area by javascript and once unchecked, it will be popped from the array... here's the codes:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get" id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk1" value = "CheckBox1" onclick ='checkTickArea(this.id)'> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk2" value = "CheckBox2" onclick = 'checkTickArea(this.id)'> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk3" value = "CheckBox3" onclick = 'checkTickArea(this.id)'> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk4" value = "CheckBox4" onclick = 'checkTickArea(this.id)'> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk5" value = "CheckBox5" onclick = 'checkTickArea(this.id)'>
    <textarea id= "taSignOff" style="width:180px;height:90px;font-size:20px; resize: none;" rows="3" readonly> </textarea>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var selectedvalue=[];
function checkTickArea(id)
   {

       $('#'+id).change(function () {
           //If checked then push the value
           if( $('#'+id).is(":checked"))
           {
               selectedvalue.push($('#'+id).attr("value"));
           }else
           {
               //This is what pops the value from the array when the checkbox is unchecked.
             /*  var index = selectedvalue.indexOf($('#'+id).attr("value"));
               if (index > -1) {
                   selectedvalue.splice(index, 1);
               }*/
               selectedvalue.splice(selectedvalue.indexOf($(this).attr("value")),1);
           }
           document.getElementById('taSignOff').value = selectedvalue.join("->\n");
       });
   }
```

Also, this function only works in firefox... But in Chrome and IE, it doesn't work...

Comment: ...well where's the `checkTickArea` function?

Comment: show us the javascript you have tried

Comment: sorry i forgot to add... there you go, i edited the question now... @DoorknobofSnow

Comment: sorry i forgot to add... there you go, i edited the question now... @leemo

Comment: So every time you click a checkbox, you add another onchange event handler ?

Comment: `$('#'+id).attr("value");` should be `$('#'+id).val();` as should `$(this).attr("value");` be `$(this).val();`

Comment: @adeneo yes because if i unchecked a checkbox, it should be popped from the array..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, although I don't know why you don't use jQuery for the textarea: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/argo49/C2hfW/2/)**

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get" id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk1" value = "CheckBox1" /> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk2" value = "CheckBox2" /> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk3" value = "CheckBox3" /> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk4" value = "CheckBox4" /> 
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chk5" value = "CheckBox5" />
    <textarea id= "taSignOff" style="width:180px;height:90px;font-size:20px; resize: none;" rows="3" readonly> </textarea>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var selectedvalue = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', checkTickArea);

function checkTickArea() {

    //If checked then push the value
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        selectedvalue.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        selectedvalue.splice(selectedvalue.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
    }

    // Why not use jQuery tho?
    //$('taSignOff').val(selectedvalue.join("->\n"));
    document.getElementById('taSignOff').value = selectedvalue.join("->\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline javascript and do :

```
var elems = $('[id^="chk"]');

elems.on('change', function() {
    $('#taSignOff').val(
        elems.filter(':checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join("->\n")
    );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YRKjj/)